# Issues in testing REST API with httpie

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have created an API for CURD operation in Django REST from Rest browsable API I can view/update/delete records . But when I trie dto perform update via httpie it doesn't work.

Url - > `http://localhost:8000/api/user/profile/1/`

Result from browser->

```
 {
    "user": 3,
    "subject": [
        1,
        3,
        4
    ],
    "phone": "897897897",
    "address": "xcgsajgchagclkk"
}
```

httpie reques -> `http PUT http://localhost:8000/api/user/profile/1/ user=3 subject=[1,2] phone=333 address=my`

Error ->

```
{
    "subject": [
        "Expected a list of items but got type \"unicode\"."
    ]
}
```

As we can see the error is in format of data sent in request but I am sending the list in subject `[1,2]` . So why its giving the error.

**Edit** : Header of my request

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 30 Oct 2015 05:33:58 GMT
Server: WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.6
Vary: Accept, Cookie
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
```

Comment: You must specify that your content is 'application/json' when you send to the server

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc in the url ?

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc actually it is json , I have dit my question please check

Comment: I've checked httpie and I think in order to pass an array you need to do:  `subject='[1,2]'` put this in quotes. Have try.

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc yes but not just inside quotes, in my case the rt syntax would be subject:='[1,2]'   ,  colons ':' in front of =

Answer (score 2):

As @BogdanIulianBursuc suggested in his comments Httpie use differnet syntax for submitting lists.

So the right syntax would be `subject:='[1,2]'`